# .NET Create New Dispatcher

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, dispatcher

I am trying to create a second thread with dispatcher so that I can have the primary dispatcher (for the UI) completely stress-free, and have the UI constantly respondant.

Now, I could create multiple threads for each sub (or void in C#), but isn't it possible for me to create one new thread and grab it's dispatcher, and invoke to that? This is what I've done:

```
Private CheckLoopThread As New System.Threading.Thread(New System.Threading.ThreadStart(AddressOf CheckLoop))

CheckLoopThread.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Lowest
CheckLoopThread.Start()
Dim Test As Windows.Threading.Dispatcher = Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.FromThread(CheckLoopThread)
```

However, the variable "Test" is after execution "Nothing". How is this possible? Is the another way to create a second dispatcher?

Answers are appreciated in any .NET form. Visual Basic or C#. I am working in VB.NET WPF on the .NET 4.0 framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that CheckLoopThread doesn't end instantly after starting it (if the thread runs a CheckLoop procedure that doesn't take long to execute).

Comment: The check loop has a loop in it, which doesn't end.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`Dispatcher.FromThread(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.fromthread) will not create a Dispatcher and will return null if a Dispatcher has not already been created for the thread.  To create a Dispatcher for a thread, you will have to access [`Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher.aspx) at least once on your `CheckLoopThread`.  As it says on MSDN for `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`:

> If a Dispatcher is not associated with the current thread, a new
> Dispatcher will be created. This is not the case with the FromThread
> method. FromThread will return null if there is not a dispatcher
> associated with the specified thread

Comment: Thank you so much! That indeed was it. +1 For you.

Comment: An important note and warning for those using **.NET Reflector** from RedGate (still  in 2021 at least, as of version 10.3.1.1956...), the product displays *patently incorrect C#* for the simple two-line function `Dispatcher.get_CurrentDisptacher`. The code incorrectly claims that a `new Dispatcher()` is created every time the `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` property is accessed. But by switching to the product's **IL** display, you can see that this is not the case.

Comment: Another warning in this area (unrelated to the bug I just mentioned) is that the design by Microsoft here is quite confusing. Namely: `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` is a (static) ***"property with side-effects"*** (boo!), while the (static) ***method*** `Dispatcher.FromThread(...)`—which basically does the same thing—is actually ***non-*** *side-effecting*. A design which swaps the semantics of these two would be clearer and would generate far fewer faulty expectations.

Answer (score 18):

Why locking?

I prefer:

```
Dispatcher myDispatcher = null;

// create a manual reset event for crossthread signalling.
var dispatcherReadyEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

// create a new thread.
new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    // get the current dispatcher (if it didn't exists
    // it will be created.
    myDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    // set the signal that the dispatcher is created.
    dispatcherReadyEvent.Set();
    // run the dispatcher.
    Dispatcher.Run();
})).Start();

// wait until the dispatcher is created on the thread.
dispatcherReadyEvent.WaitOne();

// run something on the dispatcher thread.
myDispatcher.Invoke(...);
```

Comment: Very true, although I'm not sure if the underlying implementation is the same.

Comment: Old question but, it's not. Lock uses a try block around a monitor.TryEnter call.

Answer (score 5):

I'm actually creating a lot of these dispatchers, I guess the proper way is something along the following lines:

```
object theLock = new object();
Dispatcher dispatcher = null;

lock (theLock)
{
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        lock (theLock)
        {
            dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            Monitor.Pulse(theLock);
        }
        Dispatcher.Run();
    })).Start();

    Monitor.Wait(theLock);
}

dispatcher.Invoke(...);
```

It seems complicated with all the locking, but theoretically the `Start()` method can return before `dispatcher` is actually set, so a call to to it might result in a `NullReferenceException` without the locks.

Comment: This did it for me. Thanks!